# Rails increase db value by one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Pages table in my DB with a field called position.

How can I increase that value by one before it's saved?

Even better how can I remove unused positions and give the new record the correct position number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a before_save callback:

In your Page model:

```
before_save :increase_position

def increase_position
  self.position += 1
end
```

You can add any kind of logic to the increase_position method to remove unused positions.

Comment: How could that logic look like?

Comment: Well, I cannot guess what you are trying to do with the few infos you gave us… Try to update your question and post the code of your model (at least).

Comment: when this method will be called

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the acs_as_list plugin or setup some before and after filters.

```
before_create :set_position
after_destroy :fix_positions

def set_position
   self.position = Page.count + 1
end

def fix_positions
  Page.order('position asc').all.each_with_index do |page, index|
    page.update_attribute(:position, index + 1) unless page.position == index + 1
  end
end
```